# Given a string how to generate a new string with each repeated letter?

Tags: python, string, list-comprehension, slice

Given a string like this:

```
a = 'monkeys'

b = 'hi how are you'
```

How can to generate the same string with one repeated character, for instance:

```
mmonkeys
moonkeys
monnkeys
monkkeys
monkeeys
monkeyss
```

or

```
hhi how are you
hii how are you
hi hhow are you
hi hoow are you
hi howw are you
hi how aare you
hi how arre you
hi how aree you
hi how are yyou
hi how are yoou
hi how are youu
```

I tried to use python slices, for example for the first and the last case:

```
a[:1]*1+a[:-1]+a[-1]
```

or

```
a[:-1]+a[-1:]*2
```

However, I would like to know if there is an more pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: Do you want only letters to be repeated, or any characters (including e.g. spaces)?

Comment: only letters @MartinFrodl

Comment: `hi how aree yyou` and `monkeeyys`do not fit

Comment: yes @ThomasWeller, it was a mistake let me fix it

Comment: `[a[:i] + a[i] + a[i:] for i in range(len(a)) if a[i].isalpha()]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a generator which yields strings with repeated characters:

```
a = 'monkeys'
b = 'hi how are you'

def repeater(x):
    for i in (idx for idx, char in enumerate(x) if char.isalpha()):
        yield x[:i] + x[i] + x[i:]

print(*repeater(a), sep=' | ')

# mmonkeys | moonkeys | monnkeys | monkkeys | monkeeys | monkeyys | monkeyss

print(*repeater(b), sep=' | ')

# hhi how are you | hii how are you | hi hhow are you | hi hoow are you |
# hi howw are you | hi how aare you | hi how arre you | hi how aree you |
# hi how are yyou | hi how are yoou | hi how are you
```

With Python 3.6+, you can take advantage of formatted string literals ([PEP498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)):

```
def repeater(x):
    for i in (idx for idx, char in enumerate(x) if char.isalpha()):
        yield f'{x[:i]}{x[i]}{x[i:]}'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def repeat(chars, num=1):
    return [chars[:index] + char * num + chars[index:] for index,char in enumerate(chars) if char != ' ']


repeat('monkeys', 1)
# ['mmonkeys', 'moonkeys', 'monnkeys', 'monkkeys', 'monkeeys', 'monkeyys', 'monkeyss']
repeat('monkeys', 2)
# ['mmmonkeys', 'mooonkeys', 'monnnkeys', 'monkkkeys', 'monkeeeys', 'monkeyyys', 'monkeysss']
repeat('hi how are you', 1)
# ['hhi how are you', 'hii how are you', 'hi hhow are you', 'hi hoow are you', 'hi howw are you', 'hi how aare you', 'hi how arre you', 'hi how aree you', 'hi how are yyou', 'hi how are yoou', 'hi how are youu']
```

Comment: When I read this, I don't understand what it's doing. If that's pythonic, I don't like Python :-)

Comment: how do you control the amount of repeated characters there?... What if now I want 3 instead of 2?

Comment: @anon: that was not in your question. Please do not change the scope after you have asked a question.

Comment: @anon; Then change `a[:i] + w + a[i:]` to `a[:i] + w*2 + a[i:]`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a comprehension list:

```
a = 'monkeys'

result = [a[:i] + a[i] + a[i:] for i in range(len(a)) if a[i].isalpha()]

['mmonkeys', 'moonkeys', 'monnkeys', 'monkkeys', 'monkeeys', 'monkeyys', 'monkeyss']
```